# Why C++ function can't be used as a type?

Tags: c++

What is the reason C++ function can't be used as a type to be passed as a functor or predicate?

One of the main purposes of the functor is to behave as a function so that it could be called in a function manner. Well, it could do more (have states, etc.), but why we can't use functions instead of functors it the sole purpose of the functor is to be called?

Well, the object should be constructed, as well for the functors, but this could be skipped if we see that the function was passed.

In the [code below](https://godbolt.org/z/7rd1ccfPs) both function and functor behave similarly until I try to pass them to std::map.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

bool std_span_less(const std::span<const unsigned int> lhs, const std::span<const unsigned int> rhs) {
    return std::ranges::lexicographical_compare(lhs, rhs);
}

struct std_span_less_fn {
    bool operator() (const std::span<const unsigned int> lhs, const std::span<const unsigned int> rhs) const {
        return std::ranges::lexicographical_compare(lhs, rhs);
    }
};

int main()
{
    using fn_type = bool (*)(const std::span<const unsigned int> , const std::span<const unsigned int> );

    std::vector<unsigned int> lexems = { 0, 1, 2 };

    std_span_less_fn fn_obj;
    auto span1 = std::span(&(lexems[0]), 1);
    auto span2 = std::span(&(lexems[0]), 2);

    auto res_fn = fn_obj(span1, span2); // Can be used as function
    auto res = std_span_less(span1, span2);  // Naturally used as function

    std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int, std_span_less_fn> sentences_fn;
    std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int, std_span_less> sentences; // Doesn't compile

    sentences_fn[std::span(&(lexems[0]), 1)] = 0;
    sentences_fn[std::span(&(lexems[2]), 1)] = 2;
    sentences_fn[std::span(&(lexems[1]), 1)] = 1;
}
```

Is the only reason to restrict passing functions is this object construction or I am missing something else?

I read the documentation on the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) but failed to find explicit statement what makes impossible to pass a function as `Compare` except my vague "Is function a type?" thoughts.

Comment: *"One of the main purposes of the function is to behave as a function so that it could be called in a function manner...."* **This doesn't make sense at all.**

Comment: the type of a function can be obtained with `decltype(func)` though it will be the same for all functions with the same signature, i.e. same return type and arguments. a function is not a type

Comment: One step back, since for me your question does not make sense at all. WHAT is it you want to do?

Comment: Functions aren't types. Yeah, it would be nice if it worked as you say, but currently the language doesn't have this.

Comment: You can't pass `fn_obj` either. It's not clear why you expect to be able to pass a value where a type is expected. (But try `std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int, fn_type> sentences(std_span_less);` and think about the difference.)

Comment: @user12002570, "of the **functor**", sorry for the misprint; thank you for catching this. Fixed.

Comment: @0xbachmann, this is the main part of my question. Why **int** is a type, why **struct** is a type and why function is not a type?

Comment: @DamirTenishev The function type is a type, it is just a type that you cannot create objects from.  It's like `void`.  You can't create a `void` object but you can have a `void*`

Comment: If you have `void blah(int x, int y)`, its type is `void(int, int)`. Several functions can have the same type, if they have the same parameter types, return type, etc. So, in a way, functions are similar to variables (rather than types).

Comment: @PepijnKramer, just based on the [Why std::map can't use operator < for std::span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037719/why-stdmap-cant-use-operator-for-stdspan) I decided to use 'span' instead of my type and forced to write the functor which I did and it works. I am just curios, why I have to implement a struct to have a functor with a sole purpose to get it called as a function in `std::map`. Why is it not enough to pass just a pointer to the function like in "old good times" (kidding here). Put put in a nutshell, why should I write additional lines of code, to say.

Comment: @molbdnilo, because I am curious why in this context function is not a type. What makes C++ function so different that is not a type for this case?

Comment: *"why should I write additional lines of code"* Because C++ isn't perfect. You can use `std::integral_constant` (see answer below) to create a functor from a function, to avoid writing your own.

Comment: @NathanOliver, that's what I asked in my question. Why language can't recognize function type here and avoid creating object and directly call the function?

Comment: @DamirTenishev A function is never a type. `int` is a type, but `123` isn't. `fn_type` is a type, but `std_span_less` isn't.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, I see. My question is why such a design is made in the language and if there is a way to workaround to make possible to pass function pointers to `std` algorithms.

Comment: @DamirTenishev What function should it use?  `bool(int, int)` can have an infinite amount of functions that have that type.  Which specific function to use needs some more information that the type just doesn't have.  You need a pointer so you can point to the function you want to use.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I see that this is not perfect, I am just trying to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I removed the comment as I realized it wont work here since `span` doesn't have an `operator <`

Comment: @molbdnilo, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971298/why-is-a-function-not-an-object) long discussion I still have a question, why? Again, with that discussion I could even ask for reference to standard to ask "is it really so", but let's skip this. I agree that this is true in the language. My question is why such a design decision was made.

Comment: @NathanOliver, so I want to pass not a type, but a pointer giving the library a chance to take something "common" and then make different implementation based on the passed type. Well, let's say that the most "naive" way would be to provide overload for all algorithms which would take function pointer, not a type. I understand that this is bad decision, I am just trying to say that this is possible and could be implemented better on other levels.

Comment: @DamirTenishev *My question is why such a design decision was made.* Because there is no good default value for function types.  You can't use `nullptr` because it's not a pointer.  I suppose you could have the compiler return a do nothing function but that gets tricky in C++ since some types can't be default constructed so the body of the dummy object could be impossible for the compiler to create.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you for the option with the `std::integral_constant` in the NathanOliver's answer below. That's exactly what I was looking for! And, most likely, what I was asking for, as well. I just, not knowing the answer, wasn't able to figure out the question in correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass functions as a template paramter, but you need to pass it as a pointer to the function.  The reason you need this is because a function type is exactly that, only a type, you can't create an object from it like you can with functor.  What you can do is have a pointer to a function and you can assign to that pointer what actual function it should point to.  Doing that changes

```
std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int, std_span_less> sentences;
```

to

```
std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int, decltype(std_span_less)*> sentences{&std_span_less};
                                             ^ make a pointer type  ^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                                 |            
                        initialize with a pointer to the function you want to use
```

You can alternatively use

```
std::integral_constant<decltype(&std_span_less), std_span_less>
```

as the compare type which wraps the function pointer value into the type so you do not need to initialize the map with the pointer.  That changes the code to be:

```
std::map<std::span<const unsigned int>, int,
         std::integral_constant<decltype(&std_span_less), std_span_less>> sentences;
```

Comment: You should rather pass `std::integral_constant<decltype(&std_span_less), std_span_less>`, to avoid having to store the pointer (unless you already have a functor type to pass, like OP does). Unless you intentionally want to be able to switch between functions at runtime.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Neat, didn't know about that.  I've added that into the answer.